# Are they the same python Codewars

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a problem on Codewars. Here's the problem that I'm trying to do: https://www.codewars.com/kata/550498447451fbbd7600041c/train/python

Here's my code:

```
import math
def comp(array1, array2):
    string = ""
    for i in array2:
        sqrt_i = math.sqrt(i)
        string =+ sqrt_i
    if array1 == string:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Thank you for looking at my code!

I get alot of errors but I also do get some correct as well. I am hoping I can fix my code.

Comment: Your post may contain ALL the required information to understand and solve the problem, don't share link that needs to be looked at to understand what to try to do

Comment: What happened when you tried using your code? What is supposed to happen instead, and how is that different? Please read [ask] and make sure that: 1) someone who reads **only the question and not** any external link can immediately understand **exactly what the result should be** when the code runs; 2) we can see a **specific** situation where the code does something wrong, **what** it does wrong, **why** it is wrong and **what** should be the right answer in that case instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your issues are

- values are not paired by their position, they aren't sorted the same way
- `array1 == string` you compare a list to a string, there is no way it works
- you just `=+` instead of `+=`

So as the square (root or not) keeps order, you may sort both array to compare them

```
def comp(array1, array2):
    result = []
    for power_value in array2:
        sqrt_value = math.sqrt(power_value)
        result.append(sqrt_value)
    return sorted(array1) == sorted(result)
```

Note : when you return a `True/False` based on a condition, directly return the condition

---

With list comprehension

```
def comp(array1, array2):
    return sorted(array1) == sorted([math.sqrt(power_value) for power_value in array2])
```

Comment: Your solutions fail two of the test cases.

Comment: @KellyBundy my job isn't to pass the codewars exercice. but to answer and fix the code. If there is specificities regarding the exercice, such as possible Nones, I let the OP adapt the code

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have misunderstood the Kata.

If you remove the square of each value in array1 from array2 then you can return True if array2 is empty after iterating over all values.

```
def comp(array1, array2):
    if array1 is None or array2 is None or len(array1) != len(array2):
        return False
    for x in array1:
        try:
            array2.remove(x * x)
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Hmm, they do accept this, even though it for example claims that [0] and [] are the "same".